# Enumeration flush right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate

How can I do enumeration like this:

> Some loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume
>
> ```
>             text: some info
>         Sometext: some another info
>   Somelongertext: an info
> ```
>
> loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a `description` environment instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick solution:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[text:] some info
\item[Sometext:] some another info
\item[Somelongertext:] an info
\end{itemize}
```

---

But if you want the items not to be put in the margins, you can use a tabular instead. I use `longtabu` from `tabu` package with column type `X`, to make the text wrapping properly. However, it is not suitable for long items, that produce bad page breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{@{}rX@{}}
text: & some info \\
Sometext: & some another info \\
Somelongertext: & something very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long
\end{longtabu}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second option is that exactly what I wanted to get. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\expandafter\renewcommand\csname @mklab\endcsname[1]{#1\hfil}
\begin{document}
Some loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume 
\begin{enumerate}
\item[ text:] some info
 \item[Sometext:] some another info
\item[Somelongertext:] an info
\end{enumerate}
loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume loresipsum, lores ipsume 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some explanation and not just the code alone. Also, please put a space between `\csname` and `@mklab`, then it is easier to read and will also work when the code is used in a place where `@` is a letter, e.g. inside a package.